# CGlayer drawing getting slow

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, cglayer

I am working with CGlayer drawing, I am using **3 CGlayers for drawing, named as temporary, permanent and newLayer.**

1) While drawing, I draw first into temporary Layer and on touchesEnded, I transfer data from temporary to permanent Layer and clear out temporay Layer

Here is the code

```
CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(self.permanentDrawingLayer );
CGContextDrawLayerInRect(layerContext, self.bounds, self.temporayDrawingLayer);
CGContextRef ctx = CGLayerGetContext(self.temporayDrawingLayer);
            CGContextClearRect(ctx, self.bounds);
```

Now my canvas size is dynamic, user can increase/decrease it, so whenever, user increases the canvas size, I first create a **new Layer called newDrawingLayer** draw the drawing from pemanentLayer into this NewDrawingLayer and destroy permanent Layer

Now when user tries to erase, when he clicks on erase button, I transfer data from permanentLayer to CurrentLayer and then do erase

Here is my drawRect method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{     
   switch (m_drawStep)
   {
       case DRAW:
       {

           CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


           if(self.temporayDrawingLayer == nil)
           {              
               CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);               
               self.temporayDrawingLayer = layer;
           }


           if(self.permanentDrawingLayer == nil)
           {              
               CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);              
               self.permanentDrawingLayer = layer;
           }



          CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context,rectSize, self.newDrawingLayer);
          CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, self.permanentDrawingLayer);
          CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, self.temporayDrawingLayer);

       }


        break;

       case ERASE:
       {
           CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

           if(self.temporayDrawingLayer == nil)
           {              
               CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);               
               self.currentDrawingLayer = layer;
           }


           if(self.permanentDrawingLayer == nil)
           {              
               CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);              
               self.permanentDrawingLayer = layer;
           }


           if(self.newDrawingLayer == nil)
           {

               self.newDrawingLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, self.bounds.size, NULL);
           }


           CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, rectSize, self.newDrawingLayer);
           CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, self.permanentDrawingLayer);
           CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, self.temporayDrawingLayer);
      }
           break;
}
```

The problems I am facing are

1) Whenever I erase the drawing by increasing the canvas size and then try to draw again, my drawing is extremely slow, which is not at all acceptable.

2) If I dont increase the canvas size and then perform drawing and erasing continously, I dont have any issues.

What can be the reason that the drawing gets so slow, I think, because, system is trying to draw three Layers, or is it something else, that I am not aware of, please help me out friends.
If any doubts, please ask, I will try to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a very complex system where you do a lot of copying layer content from one layer to another. That's going to be expensive.

When the user changes the canvas size are you saying that drawing is slow briefly, and then recovers, or that drawing is then slow FOREVER?

In any case, I would suggest using the instruments application to profile your code and figure out what parts are the bottlenecks. You can then use that information to figure out where to spend your time in optimization.

Comment: Firstly, if canvas size is increased and drawing is erased, then afterwards new drawing becomes slow and remains slow forever. I have tried using instruments, I ran time profiler, it says most of the time is taken by CGContextDrawLayerInRect

Comment: If you change the canvas size, you need to re-render all your drawing layers in the new size and then start doing drawing in the new size as the "native" size rather than scaling your drawing each time. Scaled rendering is going to be slow.

Comment: I am drawing using UIBezeirPaths, and converting them into CGPaths and then drawing into CGlayers, So when I increase the canvas size, I draw whatever is draw on CGlayer before size increase to new layer and then draw that newLayer on canvas and the drawing on new canvas size will continue with temporary Layer.

Comment: I can't make much sense of that run-on sentence.

Comment: ok, let me explain,   I have a canvas size of suppose 100*100, I draw a line, then I increase the canvas size,to suppose 200*200, I have a function to increase the canvas size, here what I am doing is that, I am creating a new layer with 100*100 and transferring all data from my permanent layer to this newLayer, So when user draws again, I draw both Layers on Canvas, newLayer with previousSize and permanentLayer with newSize.You can check my drawRect function above, I hope I cleared your doubt

Comment: Why draw to both layers? That will slow you down. Create a new layer at the new 200x200 size, transfer your content to the new canvas size, and discard the old layers.

Comment: Hello, So as you can see that, before increasing the canvas size, I am drawing into temporary and permanent, and after increasing the canvas size, I transfer content from temporary and permanent to newDrawingLayer and then draw all three Layers on canvas. So now you are suggesting me to instead for creating a newLayer, you are asking me to create any of the temporary/permanent layer with new size and transfer old data to it. am I right?

Comment: One morething, by transferring the content, do you mean, drawing all the paths again, or just draw the OldLayer into newLayer